# I want to open bottom sheet when clicked on the last item of BottomNavigationBarItem in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to open bottom sheet when clicked on the last item of BottomNavigationBarItem in flutter where the bottom sheet will show more screens and if I clicked on one of them it should navigate and on the other screen i want bottom bar also please help me .I also attached a photo[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOB9e.png)

I tried this plugin [PersistentBottomNavBar](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar) but still can't achieved it.
Following is the code of an item

```
   PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: "Settings",
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
            onPressed: (context) {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context!,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                useRootNavigator: true,
                builder: (final context) => Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "Exit",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
```

and in screen the last item is container

```
List<Widget> _buildScreens() => [
        MainScreen(
          menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext!,
          hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
          onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
            });
          },
        ),
        MainScreen(
          menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext!,
          hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
          onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
            });
          },
        ),
        MainScreen(
          menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext!,
          hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
          onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
            });
          },
        ),
        MainScreen(
          menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext!,
          hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
          onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      ];
```

Comment: you want to open `bottom  sheet` when clicket on `more` button?

Comment: yes i want to open a bottom sheet for more screen options

Comment: does sheet have to be over bottomNavigationBar?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter but if it can I would appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `showModalBottomSheet`, you can follow the example

```dart
class FTE extends StatelessWidget {
  const FTE({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Wrap(
                children: [
                  Text("Your More item"),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => YourScaffoldWidget(),
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Text("nav to"),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to open on click of bottom navigation bar item not using a floating action button

Comment: it would be same, on bottomNav click use `showModalBottomSheet(` as shown on this example

Comment: Ya but if I navigate the bottom navigation bar is gone but i want it to be  persist across other screens

Comment: Try using MaterialApp, route builder property

Comment: I tried that too but as I say when i Navigate the bottom bar is gone

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<Widget> allPages = [Page1(), Page2(), Page3()];
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentPageindex = 0;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue[200],
      child: Text(
        'Index 0: Home',
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green[200],
      child: Text(
        'Index 1: Account Page ',
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.purple[200],
      child: Text(
        'Index 2: Setting Page',
      ),
    ),
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3()
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index <= 2) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
        currentPageindex = index;
      });
    } else {
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Center(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                  IconButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPageindex = 3;
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPageindex = 4;
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPageindex = 5;
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ])),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(currentPageindex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.indigo,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            label: 'account',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'setting',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            label: 'more',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Page 1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[100],
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Page 2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Page 3"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But I want to navigate to other when clicked on the bottom sheet and on the other screen I want to have the bottom bar too. I already tried this I want a persistent bottom bar

Comment: so you mean items in`bottom sheet` are other items of `navigation bar `

Comment: I just add more images so that it will be clear

Comment: updated the code, check it now